# Postgresql order by and limit, the same record appears in multiple pages

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, limit

```
SELECT id, name, port, created_at, updated_at
FROM test_table
ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

All records updated_at is same since am dumping 5000 records into the database

I set page size as 10 by using limit 10 and offset 0

Issue i face is it shows a particular record of page 1 in multiple pages. Which in my case I saw that record till page-5

Can anyone tell me why this occurs and how to solve the issue

Comment: Why would you order by a column which you know has the same value across all records? You might as well not have an order in that case. Order by some other column.

Comment: @404 Even if we don't use order by, i navigate to page2, page3 etc.., a single record is shown on other pages also along with other records

Comment: If you don't put an order, and (possibly) if you put an order which is no order at all (e.g. order by NULL), then you can't guarantee that pagination will work correctly.

Comment: If updated_at is the same for all rows, then clause ORDER BY is no op, and thus order is not guaranteed - server can give you rows in any order it finds more convenient for performance. If you want to guarantee order, use unique column for ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

The order by needs to have a unique way to order your items. I would just add the id if it's unique.

```
SELECT id, name, port, created_at, updated_at
FROM test_table
ORDER BY updated_at DESC, id LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: `row_number() over ()` will suffer from exactly the same issue; if you want consistent numbering across multiple queries, you need `over (order by ...)`, and we're right back where we started. Ordering by `id` is the way to go. Handling identical records is not impossible, but all solutions (that I know of) come with some serious drawbacks, and I'd probably add a new `id` column before considering any of them.

Comment: True, and having identical records in the first place is probably not the design you want anyway.